# How to build a program with a foreign main function?

Tags: go

I'm writing a kind of framework and I would like to make the initialisation of the http server part of this framework. So basically I have a package `internal` as below which is imported by the framework middleware:

```
package internal

import(
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    checkHealth(http.DefaultServeMux)

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(handleHTTP)); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("http.ListenAndServe: %v", err)
    }
}
```

In the app code I'm looking to define the handlers in an init function.
e.g.

```
func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, world!")
}
```

However if I run `go build` in the app code directory/package it errors out that the main function is not defined:
`runtime.main_main: main.main: not defined
runtime.main_main: undefined: main.main`
 
So my question is how should I build / compile the program so and why using the standard `go build` command it doesn't find the main function defined in the internal package.

Answer (score 4):

The `main` function must be in the `main` package: [Program Execution](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

If you want a package to initialize some state at start up, or have side-effects by simply importing it, you use an [`init function`](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init). The init however must return, so you can't block with it `http.ListenAndServe`.